# Why does the XML endpoint enclose tags in &lt; instead of <

Tags: xml, soap

I'm currently dealing with a 3rd party webservice.

The XML returned has data encoded in htmlentities, I'm having to `.replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&gt;', '>')` prior to passing the data to the XML parser.

Whilst its not a huge issue it feels wrong, is this a normal practice?

**EDIT: Added an example: -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="https://www.somedomain.com/blah/service/">
&lt;xmlresponse&gt;
&lt;header&gt;
&lt;report&gt;
&lt;time&gt;14/08/2012 23:27:13&lt;/time&gt;
&lt;/report&gt;
&lt;/header&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/xmlresponse&gt;</string>
```

Comment: An in-context example of the data they're returning which requires this transformation would be helpful.

Comment: It sounds bizarre - yes post an example!

Comment: I added an example, with the sensitive information stripped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's used HTML encoding to remove the `<` and `>` characters so that it doesn't get interpreted as XML by "accident". It appears to be because the data is a `string` rather than XML elements.

Comment: Why would one embed XML in a string?

Comment: @martinblank - I don't know, but looking at your example it looks like that's what they've done.